# How to get access to a specific reducer variables as props from react without using routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm developing a react-redux app and I can get access to the reducers via routes. Now I'm facing the trouble of getting access to a specific reducer without using routes.

Here is my reducers.js:

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  topics: []
};

export default createReducer(initialState, {
  [LOADING_DATA]: (state, action) => {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      loading: action.loading
    });
  }
});
```

This is my actions.js:

```
export function loading (loading) {
  return {
    type: LOADING_DATA,
    payload: {loading}
  };
}
```

And this is what I have on my component:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import * as moduleActionCreators from '...';
import * as actionCreators from '...';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  ...
  render () {
     return (<div>
        ...
     </div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({

});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, moduleActionCreators, actionCreators), dispatch)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Normally in the `mapStateToProps` I reference the reducer variables as `loading: state['my_reference_to_reducer'].loading` but I can't figure it out how to tell the component to reference my reducers.js in order to get `loading` as props.

I would appreciate a light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the state in mapStateToProps function in order to access it:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loading: state.loading
  }
}
```

Then you should be able to use it as `this.props.loading` in MyComponent.

Your reducer can look like this:

```
export default function reducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'LOADING_DATA':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload.loading
      })
```

I recommend you to use redux ducks pattern as it keeps action creators and reducers at the same file, saves you time and makes it easier to read and use. For example:

**loading.js**

```
// Actions
const LOADING_DATA   = 'LOADING_DATA'

// Action Creators
export const loadingData = (data) => {
  return {
    type: LOADING_DATA,
    payload: {
      loading: data
    }
  }
}

// Reducer
export default function reducer(state = {
  loading: 'DATA zeroed'
}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {

    case 'LOADING_DATA':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload.loading
    })

    default:
      return state
  }   
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';
import configureStore from './configureStore'

const store = configureStore()

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent store={store}/>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import loadingData from './loading'

const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(loadingData, composeWithDevTools())
}

export default configureStore
```

**MyComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loadingData } from './loading';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.onLoadingData = this.onLoadingData.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadingData('no more undefined')
  }

  onLoadingData() {
    this.props.loadingData('DATA')
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.loading)
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>MyComponent</h2>
        <button onClick={this.onLoadingData}>Load Data</button>
        <p>{this.props.loading}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loading: state.loading
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  loadingData
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(MyComponent)
```

Comment: that way you recommend it says that this.props.loading is undefined... I've tried injecting the reducer... unsuccessfully

Comment: can you try to create a ducks module file as I added in my edit with both action creator and reducer and try again after importing it?

Comment: I'm on it... I'll be back as soon as I test it

Comment: It doesn't work for me... loading is still undefined

Comment: no problem, i just need some more time. btw you have too many things called "loading" and i need to change their names a bit to be able to access them :)

Comment: I understad. The fact is I've googleing for a while looking for a solution. The scenario is this: a reducer file, an actions file, a constants file and a react component file. I'm unable to tell the component "hey, this is your reducer".

Comment: and you also need to include your reducer into your store

Comment: Yep. I'm used to declare the reducers through routes. Then I tell the mapStateToProps the property_name: state['reducer_reference'].variable.

Comment: I added all code to the answer. If you try it you will see that loading is "undefined" when you first run the application until you press the button and trigger the action creator that updates the state. You can also add initial state to your reducer to change the state when it receives undefined